# c#, class with properties of type string array, set not working

Tags: c#, arrays, class, properties, set

I have a class that has several properties, a couple which are string arrays. When the following statement:

```
MyObj.Str1[1] = "AAA";
```

`MyObj.Str1[1]` does not contain "AAA". Using debug breakpoints, I see the set routine doesn't execute (the get routine does execute).

The property looks like:

```
public string[] Str1
{
    get { return bdr.GetArrVal(1, 25, 7); }
    set { bdr.SetArrVal(1, 25, 7, value); }
}
```

`GetArrVal()` builds and returns a string array from class internal data. `SetArrVal()` sets class internal data from the incoming array.

I tried using indexers but had too many problems passing class internal data into the class describing `Str1`.

Please note that the statement

```
MyObj.Str1 = arr1;
```

works, where `arr1` is a string array. The program breaks at the set routine.

All of this makes me think I cant do what I want. Can you assign a single element of a string-array property of an object?

Answer (score 0):

`MyObj.Str1` is a string (which is a group of characters) and `MyObj.Str1[1]` is the char on the second index of that string. You are assigning `"AAA"` **three elements** to a **single character**. This does not make any sense if you are trying to "*assign a single element of a string-array property of an object?*"

Answer (score 0):

`Str1` is the property name as posted by you `public string[] Str1 {` which returns a `string[]`. So when you say `MyObj.Str1[1] = "AAA";` you are actually trying to set a array element returned by `Str1` property and not the property itself and thus the statement `MyObj.Str1 = arr1;` works fine.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it so well.