# Copying bytes from Bitmap to byte array and back with Marshall.Copy doesn't work right

Tags: c#, bitmap, marshalling

I want to copy bytes with Marshall.Copy. My code work, but bytes is strange for me. I think I got indexes, not real bytes. If this compute and saves back, I got different colors in the image with a lot bigger byte size (image size is the same).

```
 Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imagepath);
    Width = bmp.Width;
    Height = bmp.Height;
    byte[] data;
    BitmapData bdata;
    switch (bmp.PixelFormat)
    {
      case PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed:
      {
        data = new byte[Width * Height];
        bdata = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height),ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
        Marshal.Copy(bdata.Scan0, data, 0, data.Length);
        bmp.UnlockBits(bdata);
        break;
      }
    }
```

Save image from bytes:

```
BitmapData bmData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
IntPtr pNative = bmData.Scan0;
Marshal.Copy(data, 0, pNative, Width * Height);
bmp.UnlockBits(bmData);
bmp.Save("output.gif",ImageFormat.Gif); //without format, have same problem
```

If I read color from first pixel, I got: `Color [A=0, R=0, G=0, B=2]`. Is this really color in the input image?

I don't know, why the output is soo different from the input. Where is the problem?

Example from input and output (sorry for small images):
[image: Input]
[image: Output]

Comment: I was converting Bitmap to byte array with ImageConverter class and it always worked well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not show how you created the second `bmp` for reloading the bytes. But the `PixelFormat` is `8bbpIndexed`, which means that your `data` array will contain palette indices instead of direct color information. When you create your second `bmp` with 8 bit pixel format it will use a default palette, which may be different from the original one.

So you must save the `bmp.Palette` of the first image, then use it to restore the actual colors of your second `bmp` instance.

**Update:** Though you can set the palette entries one by one, it has no effect. [Because `bmp.Palette` is a property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38927565/3427520). You must set the whole palette instead. Additionally, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32826049/5114784) is a post with indexed bitmap manipulation (see the `ConvertPixelFormat`) method.

Comment: The main thing to remember about palettes is that the getter of the palette object creates a new object instead of referencing the internal one. So you can't edit it as `bmp.Palette.Entries[0] = col`, since that only edits an unsaved copy of the image's palette.